# Numbering in theorems

Tags: numbering

I would like to have the following numbering based only on the section number:

Section 1, 
Theorem 1.1,
Example 1.2,
Example 1.3,
Corollary 1.4,
Section 2,
Theorem 2.1,
etc...

How do I obtain this?

My current setup is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\upshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
  \newtheorem{teor}[section]{Teorema}
  \newtheorem{cor}[section]{Corollario}
```

I've only reported `mythm` and `mycor` as an example.

Here's what happens with

```
\chapter{} %Parte 1%
\section{}

\begin{teor}
\end{teor}
\begin{cor}
\end{cor}
\section{}
\section{}
```

[image]

Comment: Basically it means adding things like `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection.arabic{theorem}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small *complete* code illustrating the problem?

Comment: @Bernard Edited

Answer (score 1):

You should use a trailing `[section]` optional argument for one of the statement types, and then define the others as sharing the same counter as the main one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\upshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[teor]{Corollario}
```

and similarly for the others.

If you want to remove the initial chapter number (but don't), add also

```latex
\renewcommand{\theteor}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{teor}}
```